# when exactly does drupal add entries to cache_form?

Tags: forms, caching

I have conducted the following tests on a standard drupal install to check when entries  are added to cache form:

1. Comment form exposed to anon users on article content type, every time anonymous user visit an article, no entries are added to cache form table. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jju5v.png)
2. An admin goes node/add/article, An entry is added to cache form.
3. Forms using ajax such as ajax_example module, add entries to cache form. ([Related d.o issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2819375))

Is this how cache form is supposed to work? And in case #3, does drupal generate a new entry in the table for every page request? I have seen both scenarios and unable to tell if a bug or expected behavior.

Comment: Yep I think that sounds right; forms are cached for authenticated users and when they use AJAX...I sense a follow up question maybe?

Comment: I was just trying to understand the expected normal behavior. I am triaging a use case where a form exposed to anon users generates a new entry on ever anon page request. It actually generates 2 entries `form_form_[SomeTokem]` & `form_form_state_[SOMETOKEN]`. So refresh 10 times, you get 20 new entries in the table (anon user)..is this expected behavior?  (Updated the original question ).

Comment: Not 100% sure off the top of my head, but I've definitely seen questions on here and issues on d.o that talk about massive cache_form tables caused by forms with AJAX. I think it's a known issue

Comment: It's the issue linked in your question in fact